# averages of a hashmap within a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, simpledateformat

I am trying to find the time average difference between user actions from a log file. So for example, for user action `ua, login, login` and the next user action `ua, disclaimer ok`, I want to subtract the time between the 2 actions, and for every time that specific order comes up, add those times all together and divide by the number of occurrences of that pattern.

This is my hashmap

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, NumberHolder>> uaCount =
                        new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, NumberHolder>>();
```

`NumberHolder` is defined as

```
private class NumberHolder
{
    public int occurences;
    public int sumtime_in_milliseconds;
}
```

`sCurrentLine` and `sNextLine` are what their names indicate. When iterating, `sNextLine` becomes sCurrentLine and so forth.

In my code, I loop through the log files, open them, check if a line is a user action, declare `sCurrentLine` and `sNextLine` and split those 2 lines to isolate the user action part. I then isolate the time and date of the action from both lines, use simple date format and parse them, and then I find the difference. My desired output is `ua, login, login --> ua, disclaimer, ok AVERAGE = 38 seconds`. If you want to see the whole code just ask.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @HotLicks well I don't think I need to hold the last time value, just the occurrences and the sum of the times to calculate average

Comment: My question is how to add the occurrences and sumtime into the hashmap based off the current line and next Line and how to continue that matching process

Comment: Combine the two strings into one key, using something like "|" as a separator.  You only need one level of hash.  If the object isn't there the first time, create & insert it.  After that update the totals each time.  You'll need to spin through the entries at the end to calc the averages.

Comment: @HotLicks So how should I define my hashmap then?

Comment: A hash of String -> NumberHolder, presumably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
function void addLinePair(string1, string2, deltaTime) {
    // Assumes string1 and string2 have been stripped of variable text

    keyString = string1 + "|" + string2;

    hashValue = findInHashTable(keyString);

    if (hashValue == <not found>) {

      hashValue = new NumberHolder
      insertInHashtable(hashValue, keyString)

    }

    hashValue.sumtime_in_milliseconds += deltaTime
    hashValue.occurrences++
}

function void printAverages {

    for (key,value in hashTable) {
        string1 = first part of key
        string2 = second part of key
        average = (float)value.sumtime_in_milliseconds / (float)value.occurrences
        print (string1 + " --> " + string2 + ", AVERAGE = " + average + " seconds")
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I do this? `hashValue = new NumberHolder` I am getting an error

Comment: @user2007843 - Like I said, it's pseudocode.  I assumed you knew how to create an instance of your object.

Comment: sorry java autocorrected and I didn't notice. My other question is what are you doing in the for loop?

Comment: Iterate through the hashtable.  For each key/value pair execute the loop body.  HashMap is a little clumsy this way in that you apparently need to create a Set of keys or key/value pairs, then create an Iterator over that.  There are ways to finesse this, but that an exercise for the student.

Comment: What should I define average as? I see how you declared hashValue as a NumberHolder type but how would I call .sumtime... and occurences in the for loop?

Comment: Also I need to add up the differences, I calculate the difference in the 2 times but how do I add that into the equation?

Comment: "deltaTime" is the time difference.  Average is the sum of all time differences divided by the number of differences summed.

Comment: last question, this is what I have for the beginning part, but it isn't letting me use hashValue in the if statement (duplicate variable) `String keyString = str1 + "|" + str2;
             
              NumberHolder hashValue = uaCount.get(keyString);
                    if(hashValue == null)
                    {
                     NumberHolder hashValue = new NumberHolder();
                     uaCount.put(keyString, hashValue);
                     
                    }`

Comment: Don't declare hashValue the second time -- leave off the "NumberHolder".

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to me entirely clear why you use a two-level map. If you're looking for average time, you should go through one and then to the next. i.e. average time is based on the time between each one and the one after it, not each one and every other one.

```
List<String> logLines = new List<String();

//populate logLines

getLogTime(String a, String b){
    long logTimeA = -1;
    long totalLogTime = 0;
    long count;
    for(String logLine : logLines){
        if(logLine.equals(a)){
            logTimeA = parseForTime(logLine);
        }
        else if(logLine.equals(b) && logTimeA >= 0){
            totalLogTime += logTimeA - parseForTime(logLine);
            count++
            logTimeA = -1;
        }
        //if you want it to only do the one immediately after
        else if(!logLine.equals(b)){
            logTimeA = -1;
        }
    }
    if(count == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    return totalLogTime/count;
}
```